# Setting up home media network and syncing with various devices

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, android, media-server

I am a bit inexperienced with this and all the guides I've been reading online seem to have confused/mixed terminology.

I have a projector connected to Wd tv play which is just a tv gadget that connect to my network. What I want is to setup a home media network where all my devices can access a list of media (videos, photos, music).

Some of the things I tried have worked. I created the media network using Windows Media Player on Windows 7 and WD TV Play can connect to the network and see those files and play them. That's good cause I can play local content using the network.

However, if I update my library with new videos it takes a bit of time for the network to see them and there's no way to force sync it.

What's worse is that my android phone cannot connect to this media network so I can't push content from my phone or tablet to the network.

So I've been looking at solutions out there (Software solutions only) and I am not sure what sort of setup would do this for me. I read about the potato server but I'm not sure it would work the way I want it.

Is there a cross-platform solution I could use? I don't mind if the server is running on the Windows PC as long as all devices have access to it and can sync with it on demand.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is DLNA server.

I am using Servio on my windows which is free but there are others and publishes videos and other media files to the server. It works much better than the default Windows Media player one.

On my phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy S3, there is an in-built DLNA server which can be switched on for the media, but you can also download free apps to help you do that.

To play server media on the phone I use bubbleUPnp app which is free.

Hope someone finds this useful to create a media network within their house